# XmlUnit empty Elements

Tags: xmlunit

I try to compare two xml with xmlUnit. I have the following problem. When i have two empty elements like the example below xmlUnit identificate the elements as a difference. Can i configure xmlUnit to ignore this?

`</name>` and `<name></name>`

I am only interesting in difference like the next two examples.

`<name>test1</name>` and `<name>test2</name>`

difference: test1 and test2

or

`<name>test1</name>` and `<name></name>`
difference
test1 and ...

My code:

`

```
Diff diff = new Diff(fr1, fr2);
DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
List differenceList = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
List differences = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
for (Object object : differences) {
  Difference difference = (Difference)object;
  String node1;
  String node2;
  node1 = difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getNodeName() + " " +              difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode().getNodeValue();
   node2 = difference.getTestNodeDetail().getNode().getNodeName() + " " +    difference.getTestNodeDetail().getNode().getNodeValue();
}
```

`

Comment: you mean <name/> ?? not </name>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `</name>` is a typo and it is `<name/>` as per the comment,

then you could try the following.

```
        XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
```

Seems to work for me.

ie.
When I try to compare `<Carp1></Carp1>`  with `<Carp1/>`.

Without the above setting, I get

```
Expected text value '
' but was '

' - comparing <CfgDN ...>
</CfgDN> at /CfgDN[1]/text()[19] to <CfgDN ...>

</CfgDN> at /CfgDN[1]/text()[19]
```

With the above setting, all is similar and identical.